# change hex of integer resource to String

Tags: android, hex

I am new in android.
in my value resource i create an xml layout and put this line in to it:

```
<integer name="mode_happy"> 0x1F60A</integer>
```

in my activity I want convert 0x1F60A to String. for this i create a method:

```
    private String getStringOfEmojiCode(int emogiCode) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //convert hex to char
    sb.append(Character.toChars(emogiCode));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

when I pass `mode_happy`to my method:

```
mSelectedMode = 
getStringOfEmojiCode(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mode_happy));
```

I receive this :
    `mSelectedMode: ��`

but i want to get like this:`0x1F60A`
where is my mistake?

Comment: try this `sb.append(new String(Character.toChars(emogiCode)));`

Comment: @AhmedHegazy it does not any change.

Comment: Where have you put the integer, in what file? and the same question for the layout? Ahmed why would that ever make a difference?

Comment: @NickCardoso I don't understand what do you say but I create resource layout and put my hex number in to this.I mentioned above.

Comment: You need to try this as well `mSelectedMode = 
new String(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mode_happy));`

Comment: @AhmedHegazy It doesn't any change.

Comment: Sorry I meant this `mSelectedMode = 
new String(Character.toChars(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mode_happy)));`

Comment: sayres I asked a very simple question. What you've said doesn't make sense otherwise I wouldn't have asked. Integer Resources and Layouts are completely unrelated and go in different places.

Comment: @AhmedHegazy it does not work again .same answer ` mSelectedMode: ��`

Comment: @NickCardoso I saw someone did that but unfortunately i didn't access to him.

Comment: @NickCardoso . in this tutorial : https://faranesh.com/programming/14946-retrofit-in-android#!/play/5053. it is a Persian tutorial .i do like this video but my code does not work

Comment: Persia hasn't existed for many years. I'm no longer going to try to salvage this questions seeing as you have made no effort to fix the problems. As it stands required information to answer is not in the question, which is why you're receiving silly guesses

Comment: @NickCardoso ,dude what r u saying??? I am trying to solve that an unfortunately don't find any answer to my question.thanks

Comment: Dure, r, u? Are you texting with a teenager? "???"

Comment: @NickCardoso .I am sorry man. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formatter may be used to build the string from hex characters in a particular format:

```
String mSelectedMode 
       = String.format("0x%05X", getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mode_happy));
```

This worked for me, the hex which you stored as an integer was being converted to a decimal for me, but using the formatter worked. This also meant I did not have to use any other method.

Explanation:
The format `0x%05X` takes in a 5 digit hex character signified by `%05X` with 'X' indicating hex. A lowercase x may be used which in this case would give out the output in lower case: `0x1f60a`. The `0x` is added to the format so as to have it as a prefix for each string. Refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for further details on formatting.

Comment: it's work .finally I get the answer `mSelectedMode: 0x1F60A`. thanks dude

Comment: @skbrhmn someone exist that get downvote to any post.do not be sad.

Comment: @NickCardoso I haven't worked much with formatters but my understanding is it's taking in a 5 character hex code and putting a 0x at the beginning. Is that wrong? This solves the OP's problem unless there is something I am missing.

Comment: @sayreskabir Thanks but on SO, I understand it's okay to get downvoted as long as there is something wrong with the code, I'd be happy to correct it or learn from it. No hard feelings here. Do upvote if you think this helps you and is appropriate for your specific case.

Comment: @skbrhmn .look, there is someone that give just downvote to any post :-)

Comment: I do upVote but i got this error : `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`

Comment: Code only answers should try to explain why they work if you want random people to upvote. It's doing the opposite - The pattern is matching 0x then taking the 5 characters after it, with the X (which is usually lowercase) at the end indicating it is looking at Hex. (so the 0x gets discarded)

Comment: this command `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mode_happy);` return `128522` decimal .when convert this number to hex the answer is `0x1f60a`. but this format `0x%05X` I don't know how it is work.

Comment: @NickCardoso, thanks, I updated my answer to include some explanation on the formatting.

Comment: @sayreskabir, I added some explanation, you can tweak the format if you want your output in any other way.